# Cannot use attr with an object in D3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying to convert a nice D3 chart example ( https://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/HdwTH/ ) to an Angular2 component with the new D3 v4.

I do however get a "cannot read property text of null" exception with the following code:

```
var textLabels = labelGroups.append("text").attr({
    x: function (d, i) {
        var centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
        var midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
        var x = Math.cos(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
        var sign = (x > 0) ? 1 : -1
        var labelX = x + (5 * sign)
        return labelX;
    },
    y: function (d, i) {
        var centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
        var midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
        var y = Math.sin(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
        return y;
    },
    'text-anchor': function (d, i) {
        var centroid = pied_arc.centroid(d);
        var midAngle = Math.atan2(centroid[1], centroid[0]);
        var x = Math.cos(midAngle) * cDim.labelRadius;
        return (x > 0) ? "start" : "end";
    },
    'class': 'label-text'
}).text(function (d, i) {      <--------------- exception
    return d.data.label;
});
```

labelgroups is a selection, append should work, so it must be the `.attr({})` causing the problem. It does however work fine in the jsfiddle.

Has this syntax changed in D3 v4? How would it be correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### New answer

Because `d3-selection-multi` has been deprecated, the adequate solution is just using the regular `attr` method:

```
selection.attr("foo", foo)
    .attr("bar", bar)
    etc...
```

---

### Previous answer

From D3 v4 onwards you *cannot* use objects to set `attr` or `style` anymore. To do so, you have to reference the mini library D3-selection-multi:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
```

After doing that, change your code from `attr` to `attrs` (yes, like a plural):

```
var textLabels = labelGroups.append("text").attrs({
    //mind the 's' here-------------------------ˆ
});
```

Do the same for the styles: it should be `styles`, as a plural, not `style`.

If you don't want to change all this, simply do as the "regular" way: set `x`, `y`, `text-anchor` and `class` in separate `attr`.

Here is the `selection-multi` documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/blob/master/README.md#selection_attrs

Comment: Can you show a example of `the "regular" way: set x, y`? Thanks!

Comment: @Honghe.Wu like this: `selection.attr("x", foo).attr("y", bar).attr("text-anchor", baz).attr("class", foobar);`