# Multivalue maps in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, bar-chart

I was working on creating a scatter Plot using D3.js and wanted to use Multivalue maps for SVG attributes. But it does not work, neither does it throw any error.

**I just get blank rect tags in my svg as shown below:**

[image: Inspect Element in Browser]

**I'm using the following code:**

```
var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data)
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr({
                class: "bar",
                x:function(d, i){return xScale(i)},
                y: function(d){return yScale(d);},
                width: xScale.bandwidth(),
                height: function(d){return h - yScale(d);},
                fill: function(d){return 'rgb('+d*3 + ',' + d*6 + ',' + d*9 + ')';}
                          });
```

Am I doing it wrong? Because it works fine if I put them into seperate lines with a `.attr()` call for each of them.

I'm working with d3v4. Are multi value maps supported by it or not?

Comment: The problem is the use of an object in`attr` in D3 version 4. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684597/d3-v4-cannot-read-property-text-of-null/38684633#38684633

Comment: @GerardoFurtado you're saying that this functionality is no longer supported by d3??

Comment: Not anymore in D3 v4. You'll have to separate each attribute in an `attr`. Or, alternatively, download "selection-multi".

Comment: Thanks for the help @GerardoFurtado  Works fine now!!

Comment: Multi level maps are only supported till version 3. Version 4 and 5 do not have multi level maps.