# D3 Selection: .classed({}) doesn't work, nor does .style({})

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and learning it on a Lynda course "Data Visualization with D3.js". The following codes don't work to change the style of the selected elements. There are exactly the same as in the teaching exercises.

```js
d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(2)')
.classed({
'highlight': true,
'item': false,
'bigger': true})
```

However, after I run the following codes, they worked as desired.

```js
d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(2)')
.classed('highlight',true)
.classed('item', false)
.classed('bigger',true})
```

The remaining classes seem to use ({}) a lot in .classed and .style. Some answers online suggest the problem stems from the wrong version of D3 where .classed({}) or .style({}) don't work. How can I solve this? The following are my html and css codes.

HTML Codes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>D3 Graphic</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>D3 Graphic</h2>
    <section id="chart">
     <div class="item">Barot Bellingham</div>
     <div class="item">Hassum Harrod</div>
     <div class="item">Jennifer Jerome</div>
     <div class="item">Richard Tweet</div>
     <div class="item">Lorenzo Garcia</div>
     <div class="item">Xhou Ta</div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="d3.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS codes

```css
.highlight {
  color: #C64C6F;
  font-weight: 600; 
}

.item { 
  padding-left: 30px; 
}

.bigger {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 v4 - cannot read property text of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684597/d3-v4-cannot-read-property-text-of-null)

Answer (score 3):

d3v4 moved away from using object literals (i.e. `{}`) to set attributes, classes, and styles. You can add support back for setting attributes and styles by including d3-selection-multi (https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js), and calling `.attrs` or `.styles` instead of `.attr` or `.style`

Unfortunately d3-selection-multi doesn't appear to readd support for `.classed({})`. You can set (or unset) multiple classes by calling `selection.classed('class1 class2', true)`, but there doesn't appear to be a way to set some classes and unset other classes with just one function call in v4.

Alternatively, you can use the previous version of d3 by changing http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js to http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js.

**References**
https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_classed
https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#classed

Comment: Thank you, Steve! Could you also tell me how exactly I should add the support back https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js? Should it be inserted in the html, css or js codes?

Comment: you should add it in html, right below d3.v4.min.js