# D3 text-anchor won't append

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

```
var w = 300;
var h = 150;
var padding = 2;
var dataset =[5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

function colorPicker(v){
  if (v<=20) { return "#666666"; }
  else if (v>20) { return "#FF0033"; }
}

svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return (i*(w/dataset.length)); })
.attr("y", function(d) { return h-(d*4); })
.attr("width", w/dataset.length-padding)
.attr("height", function(d) { return d*4;})
.attr("fill", function(d){
  return colorPicker(d);
});

svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function(d) {return d; })
.attr({"text-anchor": "middle"})
.attr({
  x: function(d, i) {return i* (w / dataset.length);},
  y: function(d) {return h - (d*4); }
});
```

I am following a D3.js tutorial and I'm trying to get the text-anchor to work, but it won't append. No text appears, can anyone shed any light into what I'm doing wrong? 
It should display the number above every rectangle
[image]

Comment: The text is showing up for me on here: https://jsfiddle.net/urbc42y8/ Is it possible that you're using an outdated version of D3 or something like that?

Comment: im using 4.2.3 http://jsbin.com/xumilevise/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You cannot use objects in the `attr()` method. This has been discussed here many times, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684597/d3-v4-cannot-read-property-text-of-null/38684633#38684633. However, I decided to not close this as a duplicate, because you have **another** problem in the code, which will not work even if you correct the objects problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *new* (not so new, actually) V4.x version, you **cannot** use objects to set the `attr()` method.

Besides that you have another problem, which will avoid the texts to be rendered: there is no `value` property in your dataset (which is just an array of numbers). Thus, it should be:

```
.text(function(d){return d})
```

Here is your code with the necessary changes:

```js
var w = 300;
var h = 150;
var padding = 2;
var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

function colorPicker(v) {
  if (v <= 20) {
    return "#666666";
  } else if (v > 20) {
    return "#FF0033";
  }
}

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return (i * (w / dataset.length));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - padding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return colorPicker(d);
  });

svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length) + ((w / dataset.length - padding) / 2);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```