# Issue with getting a 'foreignObject` d3v3 example to work in d3v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to get this example [SVG foreignObject tooltips in D3](http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411) to work with D3v4. I've been poking at it for a few hours now without success.

It d3v4, it seemed to choke on object arguments for `.attr` so I flattened those out. Now it is failing on the line below

```
var foHeight = div[0][0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

with the error *"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"*

The error will occur when one runs the code below and rolls over the violet circle. Is this an issue with how selections changed with d3v4?

Any tips?

---

```js
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 10
};
var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', width * 0.8)
  .attr('height', height * 0.8)
  .attr('x', width * 0.1)
  .attr('y', height * 0.1)
  .attr('fill', '#F8F8F8');

var foWidth = 300;
var anchor = {
  'w': width / 3,
  'h': height / 3
};
var t = 50,
  k = 15;
var tip = {
  'w': (3 / 4 * t),
  'h': k
};
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('cx', anchor.w)
  .attr('cy', anchor.h)
  .attr('fill', '#7413E8')
  .attr('opacity', 0.35)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
      .attr('x', anchor.w - tip.w)
      .attr('y', anchor.h + tip.h)
      .attr('width', foWidth)
      .attr('class', 'svg-tooltip');

    var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip');
    div.append('p')
      .attr('class', 'lead')
      .html('Holmes was certainly not a difficult man to live with.');
    div.append('p')
      .html('He was quiet in his ways, and his habits were regular. It was rare for him to be up after ten at night, and he had invariably breakfasted and gone out before I rose in the morning.');
    var foHeight = div[0][0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    fo.attr({
      'height': foHeight
    });
    svg.insert('polygon', '.svg-tooltip')
      .attr({
        'points': "0,0 0," + foHeight + " " + foWidth + "," + foHeight + " " + foWidth + ",0 " + (t) + ",0 " + tip.w + "," + (-tip.h) + " " + (t / 2) + ",0",
        'height': foHeight + tip.h,
        'width': foWidth,
        'fill': '#D8D8D8',
        'opacity': 0.75,
        'transform': 'translate(' + (anchor.w - tip.w) + ',' + (anchor.h + tip.h) + ')'
      });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    svg.selectAll('.svg-tooltip').remove();
    svg.selectAll('polygon').remove();
  });
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.svg-tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #4A22FF;
}

.lead {
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

polygon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aYYnqVVhAJ4lDammP4Qybmxg3/HVpA7/sNSCntyCyu4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>
    SVG foreignObject tooltips in D3
  </title>



</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 v3 selections used to be arrays. Not anymore in V4: now they are **objects** instead.

The [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) says:

> Selections no longer subclass Array using prototype chain injection; they are now plain objects, improving performance.

Let's show it. In D3 v3...

```js
console.log(d3.select("body"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Now in D3 v4:

```js
console.log(d3.select("body"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Therefore, since the selection is not an array anymore, this:

```
div[0]
```

... will not work.

The solution here is simple, just use `node()` to get the DOM element:

```
var foHeight = div.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 10
};
var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 480 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', width * 0.8)
  .attr('height', height * 0.8)
  .attr('x', width * 0.1)
  .attr('y', height * 0.1)
  .attr('fill', '#F8F8F8');

var foWidth = 300;
var anchor = {
  'w': width / 3,
  'h': height / 3
};
var t = 50,
  k = 15;
var tip = {
  'w': (3 / 4 * t),
  'h': k
};
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('cx', anchor.w)
  .attr('cy', anchor.h)
  .attr('fill', '#7413E8')
  .attr('opacity', 0.35)
  .on('mouseover', function() {
    var fo = svg.append('foreignObject')
      .attr('x', anchor.w - tip.w)
      .attr('y', anchor.h + tip.h)
      .attr('width', foWidth)
      .attr('class', 'svg-tooltip');

    var div = fo.append('xhtml:div')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip');
    div.append('p')
      .attr('class', 'lead')
      .html('Holmes was certainly not a difficult man to live with.');
    div.append('p')
      .html('He was quiet in his ways, and his habits were regular. It was rare for him to be up after ten at night, and he had invariably breakfasted and gone out before I rose in the morning.');
    var foHeight = div.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
    fo.attr({
      'height': foHeight
    });
    svg.insert('polygon', '.svg-tooltip')
      .attr({
        'points': "0,0 0," + foHeight + " " + foWidth + "," + foHeight + " " + foWidth + ",0 " + (t) + ",0 " + tip.w + "," + (-tip.h) + " " + (t / 2) + ",0",
        'height': foHeight + tip.h,
        'width': foWidth,
        'fill': '#D8D8D8',
        'opacity': 0.75,
        'transform': 'translate(' + (anchor.w - tip.w) + ',' + (anchor.h + tip.h) + ')'
      });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    svg.selectAll('.svg-tooltip').remove();
    svg.selectAll('polygon').remove();
  });
```

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.svg-tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #4A22FF;
}

.lead {
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

polygon {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aYYnqVVhAJ4lDammP4Qybmxg3/HVpA7/sNSCntyCyu4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>
    SVG foreignObject tooltips in D3
  </title>



</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One should note that in SVG1.1, foreignObject must have an height attribute too. This example won't work in current FF and Safari (IDK about Edge)

Comment: Thanks. Also: am I correct that `d3v4` doesn't handle objects for `attr` params as in the background for the tooltip? (e.g.  ```.attr({ 'height': 20,'width': 40,'fill': '#D8D8D8'});```). They work in d3v3 but seem to be ignored in d3v4.

Comment: @NoGrabbing yes, that's *partially* correct. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684633/5768908