# d3.js v5 method of appending line

Tags: d3.js

I have been able to adapt nearly all of my d3 v3.x visuals to v5 without too much of a fuss. All said and done, there are not *that* many differences. But we do have some changes like: `d3.svg.line() >> d3.line()` and `d3.svg.axis(scale).orient('left') >> d3.axisLeft(scale)` among others, nothing major though.

One thing I cant find documentation on is what happened to `.append('line')`. Here is a part of my script that was originally for v3 but I adapted to v5. I probably won't show the whole script because it has a lot of bells and whistles like a crosshair and gridlines and so forth. But again, **everything** works except for these few lines. I am simply trying to draw a diagonal line the goes from the origin to the top right of the graph.

```
var diagonal = graphGroup.append('line')//line 122
    .attr({x1:xScale(0), x2:xScale(1), y1:yScale(0), y2:yScale(1)})//123
    .attr('stroke','black')//124
    .attr('stroke-width',2);//125
```

The script crashes with this error citing line 124:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null

### Question

Why doesn't v5 understand this seemingly universal syntax for creating a diagonal line?

**My trouble shooting thus far**

- confirmed that existing syntax works fine with d3 v3
- when I comment out these 4 lines, the visual works perfectly, so that confirms it's these 4 lines
- I took a stab in the dark by changing the end points to strings on line 123, like: `x1` >> `'x1'` but to no avail

Comment: d3v5 does not support multi attr assignment, you have to include/load `d3-selection-multi`, or write 4 `attr` calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use attr with an object in D3 v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684597/cannot-use-attr-with-an-object-in-d3-v4)

Comment: Yes, @rioV8 is correct. That makes it a variation of the question I marked it as being a duplicate of. The explanation for the error is that when you provide just one argument to `.attr()` the method operates as a getter trying to retrieve the attribute with the given name which, obviously, does not make sense when an object ist provided. In this case the method will return null, hence the error.

Comment: wow that's tricky stuff. At least I know the proper term for it now "multi attr assignment"

Comment: I think it should be in the d3v3=>d3v4 notes that this is not supported by default anymore

Comment: From the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md): "For the sake of parsimony, the multi-value methods—where you pass an object to set multiple attributes, styles or properties simultaneously—have been extracted to [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi) and are no longer part of the default bundle. The multi-value map methods have also been renamed to plural form to reduce overload: selection.attrs, selection.styles and selection.properties." @rioV8