# How to create svg lines with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to adapt this example to my site: https://bl.ocks.org/dimitardanailov/bb12fef05c5ed56e793728ed8e84bb81

because I didn't succeed, i copied the Code line by line.
Only difference is, that I work with d3.js-v4.

I do not get this Code working. 
The variables data and endPointsData are filled correctly but in the SVG, only five empty line-tags are inserted `<line></line>`

As I understood, the `.enter().append('line').attr(lineAttributes)` should add non existing lines to the SVG, calling lineAttributes for each data-item.
Can please someone explain, how this should work if I am wrong?
What else can I do to debug the Code?

EDIT:
if I create the lines this way:

```
var lines = svg
.selectAll('line')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('line')
.attr('x1', function (d) { return d.x1 })
.attr('y1', function (d) { return d.y1 })
.attr('x2', function (d) { return d.x2 })
.attr('y2', function (d) { return d.y2 });
```

Instead of calling lineAttributes, the lines are drawn.
So what could be the reason, that lineAttributes don't work?

BTW: same with the circles

Comment: You should add an attribute like attr('path', whatever)

Comment: Hi, no, I think append('line') and the Attributes vor the two coordinates should be enough (As in the example).

I Updated the Poast above.

Comment: i'd add a 
.attr('y1', d=> console.log(d) )
to see what your working with

Comment: There are a number of changes from d3v3 to d3v4, these include not being able to set multiple attributes with an object passed to `selection.attr()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38684597/7106086), also d3.behavior.drag is now d3.drag - and the event names are now start/end rather than dragstart/dragend. There may be other relevant changes, but my d3v3 is rusty.

Comment: Oh thank you, didn't recognize that.

Comment: if you want simpler notation like example. check this plugin https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi